# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' while running the application with Gunicorn

Tags: python, django

I am getting error while running the application with gunicorn. Everything is working properly with manage.py but wsgi seems not to be working properly.

Gunicorn command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 basicprojectmanagement.wsgi

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'basicprojectmanagement.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Versions:
Django==4.0.2
gunicorn=20.1.0

Error

```
(venv) root@vmi819232:/home/neotricinsights/neotricinsights# gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 basicprojectmanagement.wsgi
[2022-03-30 04:36:38 -0500] [223346] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2022-03-30 04:36:38 -0500] [223346] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (223346)
[2022-03-30 04:36:38 -0500] [223346] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-03-30 04:36:38 -0500] [223348] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 223348
[2022-03-30 04:36:38 -0500] [223348] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 383, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/neotricinsights/neotricinsights/basicprojectmanagement/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[2022-03-30 04:36:38 -0500] [223348] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 223348)
[2022-03-30 04:36:38 -0500] [223346] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-03-30 04:36:38 -0500] [223346] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command
`pip install django` make sure you have deactivated the virtual environment then run the above command because sometimes it is installed in your environment but also required in your system so that's why to run this command after deactivating the virtual environment then activate the virtual environment again run this command.

I don't know why but it is the silly kind of problem :)

Comment: That's weird. Could it be that you had to install django in the base environment because the venv is not activated properly in your process? In any case, can you confirm this really solved the same problem OP describes, i.e., you were running a process with `gunicorn`, and installing django in your base environment is what you had to do to make it work?